# How do you make a bindings view in a Interface Builder Plugin (IBPlugin)

Tags: interface-builder, plugins, ibplugin

I am trying to make  property have a bindings inspector view like the textfield has for it's value. With a combo of all nonview items that has a checkbox toggle if you want to enable the binding or not.

I get how to make an IBPlugin with outlets and actions but I can't figure out how to get a popupbutton with available objects in the nib though....

Is there an IB tool to setup this type of view or do you need to create the whole thing manually using a BOOL enableBindings attribute,  object to bind to attribute, keypath, and etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(NSArray *)exposedBindings;
```